# Bootstrap nested dismissible alert

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, alert

How can I build a nested dismissible alerts in bootstrap.

The idea is to have a box (a filter) with boxes inside (filter-criteria) and have the user click crosses to delete the entire filter of just a filter criteria.

*** EDIT ***

Given the feedback I came up with the following :

```
<div class="alert alert-info NewsAudienceFilterContainer col-md-12 " id="0" style="">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <span class="filter-option">
        <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Werkjaar : 2016 - 2017
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </span>

    <span class="filter-option">
        <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Activiteit : Piano
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </span>

    <span class="filter-option">
        <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Lesgever / Coach : Piano Heleen
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </span>

    <span class="filter-option">
        <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Dag : Maandag
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Problem : when clicking on the X of the filter-options, the entire filter disappears.

Compare to the sample. I've used `<span>` in stead of `<div>`. Is that the reason ?

*** EDIT 2 *** Functioning workaround.Add an id to the 'filter-option' and use 'data-target' attribute on the button.

```
<span class="filter-option" id="DayOfWeekFilter242375497">
    <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#DayOfWeekFilter242375497">
        Dag : Woensdag
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <input name="NewsAudienceFilter.DayOfWeek" type="hidden" value="Wednesday">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functioning workaround.Add an id to the 'filter-option' and use 'data-target' attribute on the button.

```
<span class="filter-option" id="DayOfWeekFilter242375497">
    <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#DayOfWeekFilter242375497">
        Dag : Woensdag
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <input name="NewsAudienceFilter.DayOfWeek" type="hidden" value="Wednesday">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronaldbijker/40p3a1x2/1/) for this based on bootstrap framework as you've requisted.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Example
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <button type="button" class="close" id="close-filter-box" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <div class="panel-heading">Filter box with filter-criteria</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="filter-option">
          <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Filter 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Filter 2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Filter 3 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Filter 4 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <button class="btn btn-info filter" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
            Filter 5 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#close-filter-box {
  margin: 10px;
}

.filter {
  margin: 5px;
}

.filter .glyphicon-remove {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  opacity: .7;
}

.filter .glyphicon-remove:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I hope this comes close to what you try to achieve.

Comment: thx. Looks great but it does not behave what I was looking for. When clicked on the upper-right cross. The entire filter should disaspear. I move a </div> to the end to accomplish that. When clicked on one of the individual criteria. That one should disasppear. That does not happen, that is the core of my question. I can do this with a script but would like to do that with bootstrap.

Comment: I've updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronaldbijker/40p3a1x2/1/) and the code. The idea is to add `data-dismiss="alert"` to the close buttons. The close button must be the first child of the dismissible element.

Comment: Thx. Fiddler works as designed, but real-life page adapted from sample does not. I added my code in an EDIT of the Question.

Comment: When I copy/paste your code in to my fiddle it works just fine. What version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Working in VS2015 Bootstrap NugetPackage version 3.3.5

Comment: Upgraded tot 3.3.7. No change.

Comment: Found a rather dirty work-around. I add an Id to all filter-option tags and use data-target on the button.

Comment: Update to the latest version of bootstrap (3.3.7) or add class `alert` to `<span class="filter-option">`: `<span class="alert filter-option">`.

Comment: Update did not do the trick, neither adding alert. But  mentioning data-dismiss put me on the trail of a functioning work-around using data-target.   Details see Edit2.